# Is the journal "The Winnower" scientifically trustworthy?

Tags: journals, peer-review

[The Winnower](https://www.thewinnower.com) is a journal that offers a post-publication peer review, meaning that reviews of people can be written after online publication. There is no classical peer-review by a scientific committee prior to publication. If there are reviews to an article posted, we cannot know whether it is a "normal" person with no scientific background or a prof. Only upvotes and downvotes can be made.

After a long search in Google Scholar I found articles in this journal that were cited by other authors.

Is this journal trustworthy?

Comment: I'm thinking it should not be considered different than arxiv as far as "trustworthy" ... that is: "no".

Comment: What do you mean by "trustworthy"?  In what specific way are you looking to "trust" the joural?

Comment: I mean with "thrustworthy" that articles in The Winnower may be accepted by scientific workers such that These articles can be cited.

Comment: Articles can be cited no matter where, or even whether, they are published.

Comment: @JeffE This bears repeating. There is a citation in a *very* good journal to WoWWiki, because I put it there.

Answer (score 4):

"Scientifically Trustworthy" is not something with a fixed meaning. But lets break down some things that it could mean:

- Is this as good as a peer-reviewed journal?: If you believe in pre-publication peer review, the answer to this is clearly "No". The Winnower is an experiment, a philosophical stance, an an extreme exercise in transparency in the publishing of scholarly material.
- Does it have the reputation of a good journal in X field: Again, probably not. I do know some people who have considered fairly extreme principled stands in favor of the same things The Winnower supports - open science and post-pub peer review, who look on it favorably, but I very much doubt it carries much weight in most fields - at least the ones I'm familiar with.
- Does it count as a publication?: Maybe. This will very much depend on whose reading your CV, etc.
- Is it predatory?: With it being free to post things, and a DOI being relatively cheap, I think it's hard to argue that The Winnower falls in the category of a predatory journal.

But mostly, I think the question betrays a misunderstanding of what The Winnower *wants*. The whole stance behind the site is that you shouldn't "trust" a journal because it's *The Journal of Whatever*. You should interrogate what's published there yourself, and the back and forth between reader and author should be made public.